# Proper menaging buttons in layout - Android Studio

Tags: android, layout

I want to put 4 buttons in in 2x2 way, but I would like to make their width constance as half of a screen. How to do it, when I want to keep it on horizontal mode too (so in horiozontal mode they have the same place and half of screen width)?
This is current my layout.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#EB0808">
<!--    tools:context=".MainActivity">-->

<Button
    android:id="@+id/buttonSecondAnswer"
    android:layout_width="186dp"
    android:layout_height="104dp"
    android:text="Button"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.967"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/questionContentTextView"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.054" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/questionNumberTextView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="Question 1"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textSize="32sp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/questionContentTextView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="72dp"
    android:text="someQuestionContent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/buttonFirstAnswer"
    android:layout_width="186dp"
    android:layout_height="104dp"
    android:text="Button"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.022"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/questionContentTextView"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.054" />
```

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So if you put items in a horizontal/vertical chain, if you set the width/height to `0dp`, it will occupy whatever space is available on the x/y axis. For more info visit: https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#EB0808">
        <!--    tools:context=".MainActivity">-->


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/button2"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/button1" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/button1"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/button4"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button4"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/button3"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/button3" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```